# is corona sdk support revmob ads for amazon?

Tags: coronasdk, revmob

I have integerated  revmob ads in corona sdk for android and ios.But there is no information whether corona supports revmob for amazon/kindle?So please inform me about revmob ads in corona for amazon asap?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the corona SDK is supposed to support Amazon store.
You only need to create an App ID for Amazon App on you panel.